# How to use minikube when connected to AWS VPN

Tags: minikube

I am trying to use minikube whilst connected to my work's VPN (AWS VPN).

However minikube is unable to pull docker images and i believe its because its not connect to the internet when im using the AWS VPN.

I know this because im uanble to ping google.

```
minikube ssh                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
docker@minikube:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.2.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

However it does work without AWS VPN.

But if i connect to AWS VPN once, i have to restart my computer for it to work.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04